# How can I dynamically assign test groups to test methods and @BeforeXXX and @AfterXXX annotated methods during runtime?

Tags: java, testng, testng-dataprovider, testng.xml, testng-annotation-test

**My Requirement:**

I have around 100 tests in my test suite.

I don't want to hardcode the group name in the tests source code.

I want to choose the tests that I want to run each time but want to pass that list from an external source (`csv`/`json`/`xml`, etc) to the `TestNG` program via a `maven` command.

I can parameterize in the source code if needed, something like below:

```
@Test(groups = {"param1toBeReadFromExternalFile"})
@BeforeClass(groups = {"param1toBeReadFromExternalFile"})
```

Is this something that is achievable in `TestNG`?

**Reason for this requirement:**

The requirement is for external teams (that don't have access to source code) to be able to tag selective tests from the 100 tests with a specific group name and run tests on the fly without the need to check-out and check-in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you do it.

1. You first build an implementation of `org.testng.IAnnotationTransformer` and `org.testng.IAlterSuiteListener`
2. Within this implementation's constructor, you read/parse the JSON/CSV/XML/YAML file that contains the method to group mapping.
3. Within the `transform()` method, you filter out methods that match the incoming method and then add the groups as found in the data source file from (2).
4. Within the `alter()` you read a JVM argument that hints at which groups to be filtered and then apply that filter accordingly.

Here's a full fledged sample that uses the Google Gson library for json parsing.

Here's my test class

```java
package com.rationaleemotions.runtime;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.Reporter;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class DemoClass1 {

  @Test
  public void testMethod1() {
    printer();
  }

  @Test
  public void testMethod2() {
    printer();
  }

  private static void printer() {
    ITestResult itr = Reporter.getCurrentTestResult();
    System.err.println(itr.getMethod().getQualifiedName() + " belongs to the groups " +
        Arrays.stream(itr.getMethod().getGroups()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
  }
}
```

Here's how the listener would look like

```java
package com.rationaleemotions.runtime;

import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;
import org.testng.IAlterSuiteListener;
import org.testng.IAnnotationTransformer;
import org.testng.annotations.ITestAnnotation;
import org.testng.xml.XmlGroups;
import org.testng.xml.XmlRun;
import org.testng.xml.XmlSuite;

public class GroupChanger implements IAnnotationTransformer, IAlterSuiteListener {

  private JsonArray json;

  public GroupChanger() throws FileNotFoundException {
    String mapping = System.getProperty("mapping.file", "src/test/resources/file.json");
    if (!mapping.trim().isEmpty()) {
      json = JsonParser.parseReader(new FileReader(mapping))
          .getAsJsonArray();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void alter(List<XmlSuite> suites) {
    String groupsToRun = System.getProperty("groups", "g1");
    if (groupsToRun.equalsIgnoreCase("*")) {
      //Execute everything. So don't add groups filtering in the suite file
      return;
    }
    for (XmlSuite suite: suites) {
      XmlGroups xmlGroups = new XmlGroups();
      XmlRun xmlRun = new XmlRun();
      for (String group : groupsToRun.split(",")) {
        xmlRun.onInclude(group);
      }
      xmlGroups.setRun(xmlRun);
      suite.setGroups(xmlGroups);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void transform(ITestAnnotation annotation, Class testClass, Constructor testConstructor,
      Method testMethod) {
    if (testMethod == null) {
      return;
    }
    if (json == null) {
      return;
    }
    String fqmn = testMethod.getDeclaringClass().getCanonicalName() + "." + testMethod.getName();
    StreamSupport.stream(json.spliterator(), true)
        .filter(each -> methodName(each).equalsIgnoreCase(fqmn))
        .findFirst()
        .ifPresent(each -> {
          System.err.println("Found " + each);
          annotation.setGroups(groups(each));
        });
  }

  private static String methodName(JsonElement each) {
    return each.getAsJsonObject().get("method").getAsString();
  }

  private static String[] groups(JsonElement each) {
    return each.getAsJsonObject().get("groupName").getAsString().split(",");
  }
}
```

Here's how the suite file would look like

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="groups_suite" verbose="2">
  <listeners>
    <listener class-name="com.rationaleemotions.runtime.GroupChanger"/>
  </listeners>
  <test name="groups_test" verbose="2">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.rationaleemotions.runtime.DemoClass1"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

Here's how the json mapping would look like

```
[
  {
    "method": "com.rationaleemotions.runtime.DemoClass1.testMethod1",
    "groupName": "g1"
  },
  {
    "method": "com.rationaleemotions.runtime.DemoClass1.testMethod2",
    "groupName": "g2"
  }
]
```